# PHP-FPM not writing logs

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, logging

**PHP7.4-fpm** was writing logs to **/var/log/php7.4-fpm.log** correctly without issues, but since two days, when I open the file I get this:

```
NOTICE: error log file re-opened
```

I tried to simulate writing an error to the file by writing a PHP script but it seems like it is non-writable anymore!

I think it's not making sense to change anything in the configuration or the file permission because everything was working well.

What could be the cause and how to resolve this??

Comment: Check file permissions and restart FPM

Comment: @AliRaza it's 600 and owned by the user that runs the master PHP processes, which is the 'root' user, right permissions?

Comment: `ps aux | grep php-fpm`: This will display a list of running PHP-FPM processes and their corresponding user. make it is the one that has all the permissions

Comment: Any chance that `/var` is in a partition that is full?